# Проверка в родительском узле дочерних узлов

Tags: javascript, dom

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
if (!elem.childNodes.length) {
  console.log('Дочерних элементов нет');
} else {
  console.log('Дочерние элементы есть');
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div>
    <p>text 1</p>
    <p>text 2</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Не работает проверка. Не получается найти ошибку, что не так?

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByTagName` Надо перебирать как массив

`childnodes` также воспринимает пробелы и текст за детей так что лучше `child`

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
  let rc = i + 1;
  
  if (elem[i].children.length === 0) {
    console.log('У дива №' + rc + ' дочерних элементов нет');
  } else {
    console.log('У дива №' + rc + ' дочерние элементы есть');
  }
  
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div>
    <p>text 1</p>
    <p>text 2</p>
  </div>
</footer>
<footer>
  <div></div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp

```
var divElements = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
if (divElements.length > 0) {
  if (divElements[0].childNodes.length == 0) { 
    console.log('Дочерних элементов нет');
  } else {
    console.log('Дочерние элементы есть');
  }
} else {
  console.log('DIV элементов нет');
}
```

Comment: спасибо! Но мне конкретно интересно почему у меня проверка не работает !elem.childNodes.length

Comment: @ikar, потому что у тебя elem - массивоподобный объект, а не элемент.

Comment: А я думал переменная в которую записан объект div.

Comment: @ikar множественное число `...Elements...` в `getElementsByTagName` ничего не подсказывает?